# Terminal, Prompt changed to “-Bash-3.2” and all shell script in server gone

Tags: bash, terminal

Usually my terminal prompt was

```
username $
```

after the weekend the prompt changed to below

```
bash-3.2#
```

and all my shell script in the server all gone/missing.
but the perl script still there.
i have no idea what going on, any suggestion or advice can provide?

Comment: Check your user, command `id`

Comment: @RomeoNinov
bash-3.2# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel)


normally i will login with root user

Comment: Based on your question before you enter as ordinary user. So search your files in `/home/username` where `username` is the user you use in the past